# No Space Between Attributes error

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList" onclick="document.forms["searchform"].submit();return false"> </div>
```

When i right click on firefox and view source on my site i got above code has an error : No Space Between Attributes

where is that space?

Comment: Change to single quotes around `'searchform'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

maybe try changing `document.forms["searchform"]` to `document.forms['searchform']`

Comment: I had the same error, it turned out that I had accidentally put the last semi-colon of my style section outside the closing quote e.g. <div style='color:red';>  I wish this error was more general i.e. "Non fatal formatting error"

Answer (score 3):

You need to nest your quotes properly:

`<div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList" onclick="document.forms['searchform'].submit();return false"> </div>`

Using a text editor with syntax highlighting can make it a lot easier to spot these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Escape your double quotes, or use single quotes

You can escape them using backslash: `attr="this.something[\"key\"]=value"` or whatever you want.

Cleaner to use single quotes though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="document.forms["searchform"].submit();return false"
```

should be

```
onclick="document.forms['searchform'].submit();return false"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in the onclick attribute:

```
onclick="document.forms["searchform"].submit();return false"
```

You could write instead

```
onclick="document.forms['searchform'].submit();return false"
```